# Study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the behaviour of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$$.
I have tried to use the comparison test considering that $\log{(n)}>1$ definitely and $1+\cos{(n)}<n+1$, then:
$$\frac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}>\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
Now the series of $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ converges but this does tell me anything about the convergence of the original series.

**Can you help me in studying this series?**

Comment: Hint:  The denominator is very close to $n^3$ and the numerator grows slower than $n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use *asymptotic equivalence*:

- $\log n=_\infty o(n)$, so $n+\log n\sim_\infty n$;
- $\cos n$ is bounded, therefore $n+\cos n\sim_\infty n$.

Can you proceed from there?

Comment: But in this way i would obtain that the general term is asymptotic to $1/n^2$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  So you can conclude.

Comment: in this way so the series is convergent, right?

Comment: Absolutely. However, for a full justification, don't forget to mention the given series has ultimately positive terms.

Comment: Oh yes I agree. Can you give some hints for proving this last thing?

Comment: It's easy to check that both numerator and denominator are positive if $n>1$.

Comment: @cely $f(n) = o(g(n))$ means $\forall c > 0 \exists k > 0$ such that $0 ≤ f(n) < cg(n) \,\, \forall n ≥ k$

Comment: Dearest Bernard did you give me your haters on MSE? I have continuous negative votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Show that *eventually* the following estimates hold
$$\frac{n+\log(n)}{(n+\cos(n))^3}<\frac{n+n}{(n-1)^3}\leq\frac{3}{(n-1)^2}.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: Is it sufficient to say that: log(n)<n for all n and $cos(n)\leq -1$ for all n?

Comment: $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}, cos(n) \leq +1$. You made a mistake when you wrote $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}, cos(n) \leq -1$. Did you mean to write that $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}, cos(n) \geq -1$?

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geq 2$ we have

$$\frac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}<\frac{n+n}{\left(n-\frac{n}{2}\right)^3}=\frac{2n}{\frac{n^3}{8}}=\frac{16}{n^2}$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}<\frac{1}{1+\cos(1)}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{16}{n^2}=\frac{1}{1+\cos(1)}+\frac{8 \pi ^2}{3}-16$$

Answer (score 0):

### Observation One

#### Informal Section of Observation One

For very large values of $n$, ${(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$ is aproximatly equal to $n^{3}$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$

#### Formal Section of Observation One

***Special Theory of Observation One***

> $\forall \epsilon \in \left\{r \in \mathbb{R}: r > 0 \right\},$
>   $\exists k \in \mathbb{N} :$
>     $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},$
>        $n \geq k \implies \biggl|(n+\cos{(n)})^{3} - n^{3} \biggr| < \epsilon$

***General Theory of Observation One***

> $\forall F, G \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R},$
>   $\forall \epsilon \in \{r \in \mathbb{R}: r > 0\},$
>     $\exists k \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k \implies \biggl|{F(n) - G(n)} \biggr| < \epsilon$

### Observation Two

***Informal & General Section of Observation Two***

> If function $F$ and function $G$ looks pretty similar to each-other as you go really really far to the right (along the x-axis), then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(F(n))$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(G(n))$ converges

***Formal and Special Section of Observation Two***

> If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$ converges then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{n^{3}}$

***Formal and General Section of Observation Two***

> $\forall F, G, H \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R},$
>   If
>      $\forall \epsilon \in \{r \in \mathbb{R}: r > 0\}, \exists k \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k \implies \biggl| {F(n) - G(n)}               \biggr| < \epsilon$
>   then
>     $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(F(n))$ converges
>       if and only if
>     $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(G(n))$ converges

***Informal & Special Section of Section of Observation Two***

> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{n^{3}}$ converges

#### Observation 3

> For very large values of $n, \quad n+\log{(n)} \approx n$.
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+\log{(n)}}{(n+\cos{(n)})^3}$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{n^{3}}$ converges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very exhaustive question